# SQLite3 Prepared Statement in PHP5

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to use prepared statements for a select query in php for an sqlite3 database but without any success. I'm trying it with the following code:

```
$db = new SQLite3('/var/www/sqlite/data.db');
$link = "http://127.0.0.1";
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE link = (?)');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $link, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$result = $stmt->execute();
var_dump($result);
```

No result.

```
object(SQLite3Result)#3 (0) { }
```

What is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the results:

```
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

Comment: Thank you works well! I was looking for the mistake at a wrong part of it.